# Finding the bitmap in bigger bitmap (Pixel bot) - How to make it/for loops faster?

Tags: c#, bitmap, pixel, bots

so this function is finding a bitmap in bigger bitmap.. buuuut .. it takes like 4-6s to go through 1920x1080 screen..
I wouldn't be asking you if I 100% understood to that code, which I dont, I am a newbie in programming and my logic is kinda sleeping already (4:00 AM).. (Code is from video tutorial, i was using it for a long time without even studying it :D)

So what do I exactly want is to make a bot finding pixels/pictures in the game and then clicking it, but 4-6s is pretty long, aint it ? I was pretty curious about this, because pixel bots for several games made in other programming languages are pretty, pretty fast ! Like 1s...
So I was like, its caused by c# ? It probably aint caused by c# .. but this code is proly working, but maybe it doesnt need to be that long ? 
I thought about "getting faster loops" .. but thats aint happening probably.

Try to invent some solution, I will be very grateful ! And I still think that this problem might be important to solve for many other people.

```
private bool FindBitmap(Bitmap bmpNeedle, Bitmap bmpHaystack, out Point location)
{
    for (int outerX = 0; outerX < bmpHaystack.Width - bmpNeedle.Width; outerX++)
    {
        for (int outerY = 0; outerY < bmpHaystack.Height - bmpNeedle.Height; outerY++)
        {
            for (int innerX = 0; innerX < bmpNeedle.Width; innerX++)
            {
                for (int innerY = 0; innerY < bmpNeedle.Height; innerY++)
                {
                    Color cNeedle = bmpNeedle.GetPixel(innerX, innerY);
                    Color cHaystack = bmpHaystack.GetPixel(innerX + outerX, innerY + outerY);

                    if (cNeedle.R != cHaystack.R || cNeedle.G != cHaystack.G || cNeedle.B != cHaystack.B)
                    {
                        goto notFound;
                    }
                }
            }
            location = new Point(outerX, outerY);
            return true;

        notFound:
            continue;
        }
    }
    location = Point.Empty;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: `LockBits` and a pointer.  `GetPixel` is very slow and only appropriate for trivial image processing/analysis tasks.

Comment: Ed S is correct. The good news is that LockBits will let you use the loops almost unchanged. You will have to switch X and Y though, which are wrong (speedwise) in the solution anyway and you will have to compare each channel separately, taking care of the pixelformat.

Comment: Note that the code will compare each pixel for equality. This means that there is almost no chance to find the needle if the images are in jpeg!

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a little class for it using **LockBits** and **unsafe** code.
The performance is great.
I decided to use uint values instead of colors.
For converting you can use http://www.vcskicks.com/color-uint.php

```
/// <summary>
///     Represents a bitmap with bit functions.
/// </summary>
public class LockedBitmap
{
private Rectangle _bounds;

/// <summary>
///     Gets or sets the bitmap.
/// </summary>
public Bitmap Bitmap { get; set; }

/// <summary>
///     Gets or sets the values of the bitmap.
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>Watch at the static length!</remarks>
public uint[] Buffer { get; set; }

/// <summary>
///     Gets or sets the bitmap data.
/// </summary>
public BitmapData BitmapData { get; set; }

/// <summary>
///     Initializes a new instance of <see cref="LockedBitmap" />.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="bitmap">The processed bitmap.</param>
public LockedBitmap(Bitmap bitmap)
{
    this.Bitmap = bitmap;
}

/// <summary>
///     Locks a Bitmap into system memory.
/// </summary>
public unsafe void LockBits()
{
    var width = this.Bitmap.Width;
    var height = this.Bitmap.Height;

    var imageLockMode = ImageLockMode.UserInputBuffer;

    // Setting imageLockMode
    imageLockMode = imageLockMode | ImageLockMode.ReadOnly;
    imageLockMode = imageLockMode | ImageLockMode.WriteOnly;

    // Save the bouunds
    this._bounds = new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height);

    // Create Pointer
    var someBuffer = new uint[width*height];
    // Pin someBuffer
    fixed (uint* buffer = someBuffer) //pin
    {
        // Create new bitmap data.
        var temporaryData = new BitmapData
        {
            Width = width,
            Height = height,
            PixelFormat = PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb,
            Stride = width*4,
            Scan0 = (IntPtr) buffer
        };

        // Get the data
        this.BitmapData = this.Bitmap.LockBits(this._bounds, imageLockMode, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb,
            temporaryData);
        // Set values
        this.Buffer = someBuffer;
    }
}

/// <summary>
///     Unlocks this Bitmap from system memory.
/// </summary>
public void UnlockBits()
{
    this.Bitmap.UnlockBits(this.BitmapData);
}

/// <summary>
///     Iterate through all pixel values.
/// </summary>
public unsafe void Iterate()
{
    // Dimension
    var width = this.Bitmap.Width;
    var height = this.Bitmap.Height;
    // Actual uint position
    int cp = 0;
    // Pointer at the fist uint
    var scp = (uint*)this.BitmapData.Scan0;
    // Stick the array
    fixed (uint* cb = this.Buffer)

        // Step through each pixel
        for (uint* cbp = cb, cbdest = cb + this.Buffer.Length; cbp < cbdest; cbp++)
        {
            // Get x and y from position
            var x = cp % width;
            var y = cp / width;

            var color = *cbp;

            cp++;  // Increment cp
        }
}
}
```

Example usage:

```
using (OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog())
{
    if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        Image image = Image.FromFile(ofd.FileName);
        LockedBitmap locked = new LockedBitmap((Bitmap) image);
        locked.LockBits();
        locked.Iterate();
        locked.UnlockBits();
    }
}
```

**color** has now the value of the pixel's color. cp is the absolut position (1D)
and (x|y) the point position in the bitmap (2D)

Comment: Could you upload somewhere whole project ? I am seriously new in C# programming, I don't know how to use this piece of code. I'd be grateful.

Comment: @user3690993 I added an example for you.